# GWT JSONPRequestBuilder - "Unknown Token :" error in browser console with Timeout exception at the end

Tags: gwt, rest, jsonp

I am trying to call a Restful WS from GWT using JSOPRequestBuilder. I have a similar issue which was reported in the link

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/ef93383aca7a3dfc/d4dc5bad1a9110ea

But, I could not figure out the solution. Kindly help me at the earliest.

### My JAX-WS resource code snippet from server

```
 @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public DealerAddress getDealerAddress(@QueryParam("dealerId") String sDealerId) {

       DealerAddress dlrAd = new DealerAddress("test", "test", "test", "test", 10, new Date(), new Date());
       return dlrAd;
   }
```

---

Jersey returns a JSON object of DealerAddress.

Now rest URL "https://127.0.0.1:8181/application/rest/OrderManagementResource?alt=json-in-script&dealerId=DLR1" 
works absolutely fine when i tried request in browser.

It even works with RequestBuilder approach from GWT but not with JSONPRequestBuilder approach.

### Code snippet to invoke WS from GWT using JSONPRequestBuilder

```
JsonpRequestBuilder jsonPReqBuilder = new JsonpRequestBuilder();        
jsonPReqBuilder.setTimeout(100000);
        jsonPReqBuilder.setCallbackParam("callback");
        jsonPReqBuilder.requestObject("https://127.0.0.1:8181/application/rest/OrderManagementResource?alt=json-in-script&dealerId=DLR1" , new       AsyncCallback<DealerAddressJSON>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                caught.printStackTrace();
                Window.alert("Inside error"+caught.getLocalizedMessage());          
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DealerAddressJSON result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Window.alert("Inside success"+result);
            }

        });
```

---

where as DealerAddressJSON is a JavaScriptObject type class.

I could see that my JAX Rest resource getting called and saying returning from server.

Also, I could see that in Firebug that the response comes in browser but fails with an exception "Unknown token :" 
At the end I always get a Timeout exception. 
Now I am in big question whether the way we return JSON from JAX-RS resource is a problem in server 
or 
JSONPRequestBuilder calling procedure is a problem? I could not understand the callback changes which some of the links explained on this issue.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably sending back JSON, while the JSONPRequestBuilder expects JSONP. These are not the same thing.

JSON is just the data, as is - make the request using AJAX (i.e. the RequestBuilder), and the contents can be read directly. These requests can only be made to the same server. Example JSON data:

```
{"response":"success", "items":[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]}
```

In contrast, JSONP is designed for cross-origin requests, so instead of just containing the data, the data is wrapped up in a JavaScript. Since your JSON service isn't wrapping the a response in a js function call, this isn't working. Example JSONP data:

```
callback_1({"response":"success", "items":[{"id":1}, {"id":2}]})
```

The callback changes with each request, so the server is supposed to change that callback function based on what the client requested each time.

Comment: As you said, RequestBuilder works fine. But I would like to come out of that SOP restriction and want to use JSONPRequestBuilder. Also, I understood that return type is not of JSONP type which has a problem. I could not understand how response from server to be modified for JSONP format with call back function. Can you please tell me with respect to my code, the necessary changes for callback.

Comment: Also, if we change server to return JSONP, will that not become a tight coupling between server and GWT client. In case if we have a different client (Not GWT) and wants to make use of the same rest services from server, do we need to rewrite server changes? Because, server response JSONP should get handled by all different clients as well rt.

Comment: JSON isn't JSONP, and they can't be used in the same way - server response is almost the same, but the trick you do to get around SOP must be there for the browser to accept it - you are deliberately going around SOP, which is a security feature. The standard approach usually is to discriminate between the two somehow, maybe with a `.json` vs `.jsonp` suffix. JSONP can only use GET requests, and _must_ contain valid JavaScript, whereas a XHR is much more flexible, even when you confine it to containing JSON only.